# activeadmin, remove empty message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In ActiveAdmin, when there are no items for the model (in my example User), it shows a default 'There are no Users yet. Create one'.

[image: There are no * yet]

1. How can I remove this message?
2. Is there the possibility of customizinig it on per-page basis, that is having a particular message for a particular ActiveAdmin page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a MonkeyPatch:

Create a new file in lib folder and copy:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    # Build a Blank Slate
    class BlankSlate < ActiveAdmin::Component
      builder_method :blank_slate

      def default_class_name
        'blank_slate_container'
      end

      def build(content)
        super(span(content.html_safe, class: "blank_slate"))
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Customize the content variable in build method to change the default message.

Answer (score 2):

1. For now you cannot do it by `ActiveAdmin` settings. [Look issues in
   repository](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2808).
2. You can render any `html` or `erb.html` in your resources

Comment: ok, can you give me a hint on how to render something only if there are no records and leaving the default index when there are some?

Comment: @AgostinoX i do not understand you. Can you show some example?

Comment: if Users.count>0 then i want the page as we know it, else i want to render a custom html (so when there are no records)

Answer (score 0):

You may use poorly documented (but not so monkey-path) `blank_slate_link` index page option. It lets you override this message in any of your ActiveAdmin's resource index page.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72529909/1744707 for details.