# ActiveAdmin - blank slate - customized message - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

How can i change the blank_slate message on ActiveAdmin. Each of my models would have a different blank_slate message.

Example:

- Transport: No transports, do this and this
- Car: Did you forget, no cars until this

Comment: Did this helped you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159015/activeadmin-remove-empty-message

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala Nope, did nothing

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala Added the file to initializers, but all i got is the content, need to find a way to know from which model it was called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkey patch ActiveAdmin to load the message as desired:

```
require 'active_admin/helpers/collection'

module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Index < Base
        protected
        def render_blank_slate
          # for example only, you can define your own I18n structure
          # You can use active_admin_config.resource_label too if not mistaken
          blank_slate_content = I18n.t("active_admin.blank_slate.content.#{active_admin_config.plural_resource_label}")
          insert_tag(view_factory.blank_slate, blank_slate_content)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

load this file to the initializer folder and put the messages in your language YAML file following the structure as defined in the `blank_slate_content` assignment line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (poorly documented but not so monkey-path) `PagePresenter.blank_slate_link` option responsible for rendering a link to new resource on an empty index page ([see GitHub source](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb#L149)). You may override it in your ActiveAdmin's resource index page using `blank_slate_link` keyword in the header of the index page definition. E.g. (`app/admin/transport.rb`):

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Transport do
  # Some cool initialization: scope, filters, ...
  index blank_slate_link: 
        -> { "No transports, "+
             link_to("do this and this", new_admin_transport_path) }
  do
    # ...other index page details go here...
  end
  # ...rest of pages: show, edit, ...
end
```

This way you get as sophisticated link as you want. And the I18n's `active_admin.blank_slate.link` is no longer used for generating link to a new resource.

But as you see `render_blank_slate` still uses the hard-coded `active_admin.blank_slate.content` string to render text right before the link (e.g., "There are no %{resource_name} yet."). If you want to get rid of this text you should override it in your YAML localization file. You may simply leave it empty (`app/config/locales/en.yml`):

```
en:
  active_admin:
    blank_slate:
      content: ""
```

Or, in your case I'd suggest:

```
en:
  active_admin:
    blank_slate:
      content: "%{resource_name}: "
```

which gives you the desired "Transport: No transports, do this and this" message.