# active admin how to render form on index page if object not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I can't understand what I do wrong. My code won't work if subscription blank, but if I created it from rails c, all works fine...

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

ActiveAdmin.register Subscription do
  actions :index

  index do
    result = Subscriptions::GetPricing.call(admin: current_admin)
    if result.success?
      render partial: 'subscription_form', locals: { amount: result.plan.amount }
    else
      flash[:alert] = result.message
      render partial: 'subscription_errors'
    end
  end
end
```

Now i get:  There are no Subscriptions yet. simple message.
And i want left all styles, nav panel, etc how it default, but in container should be store my code from partials.

Comment: ActiveAdmin handles all empty pages the same way via the blank_slate.  You can override this behavior by doing some monkey patching. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159015/activeadmin-remove-empty-message

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to display an input form if the table is unpopulated then try this:

```
controller do
  def index
    collection.size == 0 ? redirect_to(new_subscription_path) : super
  end
end
```

Comment: For me worked when I user `collection.any?`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is a bit wrong. `index do` block is to render the view level mainly. If you want to override controller action you will have to do it like below -

```
controller do
 def index
   # your code here
 end
end
```

Have a look at the documentation -

https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html

https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages.html